# Comparing password to hashed passwork using bcryt in Django

Tags: python, django, hash

I am trying to compare a user entered password field to a password that has been hashed.  I have looked at the documentation and have not been able to find what I have been looking for.  I hash the password using

```
pw_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(pw_bytes, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

If I re-hash the password, it gives me a different hash.  How do I dehash the password from my db, or re-hash the password the user provided so that they match?

Comment: Your salt is different every time you run this. It SHOULD be a different hash each time. If you want a repeatable hash you need to store the salt as well.

Comment: So I should store the salt in my db?

Comment: Yes. You normally store a salt with each user record. I would recommend changing the salt whenever the user changes their password, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the results of `bcrypt.gensalt()` *with* the encrypted password and pass it again to `bcrypt()` when you hash the later password attempt.

The point of the salt is to make your hashes unique per user - said another way, if two users use the same password the hashes should ideally be different.

This salt is to protect your passwords should all the hashes be compromised.

Someone could run a hash against every word in a dictionary and then look through your hashes for matches.  These lookup tables are called *rainbow tables*.

If done properly, each password has a unique salt.  The rainbow table would then need to have an entry for every word in the dictionary *combined* with every possible salt combination.  This multiplies the required size of an already large table.

- [using non random salts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes)
- [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674904/salting-your-password-best-practices)
- [pepper vs salt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891729/best-practices-salting-peppering-passwords)